# Json.NET issues

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a simple object in C#, send it, and then deserialize it on the other end.  The first two parts seem to work fine, but when I try to do:

```
ReturnItem jsonval = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnItem>(result);
```

I get:

> 07-08 11:41:15.519 I/MonoDroid( 2856): Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"Val1":-1.0,"Val2":-1.0,"Val3":-1.0,"Val4":-1.0}" to type 'AndroidDemo.ReturnItem'. Path '', line 1, position 104. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to AndroidDemo.ReturnItem.

For reference, ReturnItem looks like:

```
public class ReturnItem
{
    public double Val1{ get; set; }
    public double Val2{ get; set; }
    public double Val3{ get; set; }
    public double Val4{ get; set; }
}
```

result is a string that looks like:

> "{\"Val1\":-1.0,\"Val2\":-1.0,\"Val3\":-1.0,\"Val4\":-1.0}"

Edit: Here is how I initially serialized ReturnItem.

```
ReturnItem value = new ReturnItem();
value.Val1= -1;
value.Val2= -1;
value.Val3= -1;
value.Val4= -1;
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
```

Comment: Is there a `List<object>` involved anywhere?

Comment: I tested this code myself using the latest version of Json.NET and it runs without an issue.

Comment: how do you serialize it?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple "ReturnItem"-Classes in different namespaces?

Comment: What is the medium you are transferring it over? And how?

Comment: @Adam There shouldn't be a List<object> anywhere.  Cyral I don't know what to tell you, it doesn't work for me.  Feras added an edit addressing that.  viertausend there shouldn't be, but I will check.  Ruslan I've got a C# REST API on localhost that I'm pulling from.  So it's serialized on a server and deserialized locally.

Comment: Can u post the code for serializing also?

Comment: @jay Added as an edit to the original post.

Comment: @viertausend I tried renaming it to MyItem, same issue.

Comment: @gmaster I tried the code you have posted and I can serialize and deserialize without any issues. Although I am doing both in the same program one after the other. Are you storing the serialized string somewhere and then getting it back? Have you tried serializing and deserializing in same program without storing or using it anywhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the double quotes around the JSON object exist in the string you're trying to deserialise?

If so then it's going to think the entire thing is a JSON representation of a string, rather than a 'ReturnItem'.

Comment: You nailed it, I cut off the leading and trailing quotes and removed all the backslashes and that solved it!

Comment: It's odd, I tried putting that string through JsonConvert in my own test app and it complained about the JSON being invalid, so I thought I was probably wrong. There must be a difference in the way the JSON string is being read in, or the deserialisation code is different on different platforms. Anyway, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the AndroidDemo.ReturnItem class is the same as the ReturnItem class in your example above.

Comment: They are identical; literally copy-pasted.